# How to import data via post deployment script from SQL Server CE into a SQL Server DB freshly created using VS database project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to import data from a *SQL Server Compact* (`.sdf`) database into a *SQL Server* database created through *Visual Studio* database project.

The `.sdf` database was created by a third party tool from an existant *SQL Server* database, and it is embedded into the *Visual Studio* project. The purpose is to deploy the database and insert initial values on a remote machine. I would like to run the import script as a post deployment script something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO Employer(
EmployerId,
EmployeeName
) SELECT
EmployerId,
EmployeeName
FROM sdfDB.dbo.Employer
```

- Is it possible to reference a *SQL Server Compact* database (`sdfDB`)
  in T-SQL script?
- If not, what is the best practice to import data
  into a freshly created DB from an embedded datasource which can be
  deployed by build script in a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) *Is it possible to reference a SQL Server Compact database (sdfDB) in
>   T-SQL script?*

If you are thinking to something like this,

```
INSERT INTO [SQL SERVER Db].Table (Values) 
SELECT (Values)
FROM [Sql Server Compact Db].Table
```

unfortunately **no**, this is not possible.

> 2) *If not, what is the best practice to import data into a freshly
>   created DB from an embedded datasource which can be deployed by build
>   script in a remote machine.*

You can use the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1), that contains features to generate scripts from a Sql server compact file, that you can use to populate the SqlServer database.

Features:

> Script!
>
> - Migrate a SQL Server Compact database directly to SQL Server (LocalDB/Express)
> - Migrate from SQL Server Compact to SQL Server, SQL Azure and SQLite via script (...)
>
> (...)

**EDIT**

Also available in api form at [exportsqlce.codeplex.com](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/). Thanks ErikEJ for comment and great job!

Comment: Is generating insert script the only way to go about it? So for each schema change we need to regenerate it.

Comment: @BijoThomas Probably not the only way but I am not I follow you. Do you want only populate the SQL Server Database?  Do you need to recreate the schema in the SQL server from the `.sdf`?

Comment: The database schema is built from the Visual studio database project. We're trying to use .sdf to populate the initial values. So each time the build script is run, the db is recreated and values added to the tables.